# Printing all Labels in a Form VB.net

Tags: vb.net, printing, label

**I want to print all labels in a form 
 how to do that?**

I have more the 12 labels in my form

Comment: Could you expand a bit on your question, please? As it stands, it is difficult to see what you are asking.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to read this *carefully*: [Ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this page for a breakdown on vb.net printing methods:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/72b5a038-912d-4455-929d-89eeb9984d7c/how-do-i-print-a-form-in-vbnet?forum=Vsexpressvb

To get the text out of all your labels, use this code:

```
For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf (ctrl) Is Label Then
        Dim newLine As String = ctrl.Name & ": " & ctrl.Text
        'Process newLine as you see fit
    End If
Next
```